# Stored Procedure concatenation mysql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE concatenation()
      BEGIN
              DECLARE i  INT default 1;
              declare t varchar(50);
              repeat 
              set @t =  concat("INSERT ignore INTO `site_values_" , i , "` (report_time) SELECT  CONCAT(", "pcu_rtc_year" , "-" , "pcu_rtc_month" , "-" , "pcu_rtc_day" , "  " , "pcu_rtc_hour" , ":" , " pcu_rtc_minute" , ":" , " pcu_rtc_secound",")" ,
                   " FROM site_values where site_id =" , i);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @t;
    EXECUTE stmt; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    set i = i+1;
    until i =1001
    end repeat;
    END;
```

I have the above code. I could create procedure. But when i call it 
call concatenation it shows

> "SQLSyntaxError (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': pcu_rtc_minute: pcu_rtc_secound) FROM site_values where site_id =1' at line 1")"

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the `"` character after `SELECT CONCAT` neccesary?

Comment: To save time, can you print out what @t looks like when the code is running and update your post?

Comment: Are pcu_rtc_year, etc. field names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the quotes around the field names.  It should look something like this:

```
concat("INSERT ignore INTO `site_values_" , i , "` (report_time) SELECT  CONCAT(pcu_rtc_year , "-" , pcu_rtc_month , "-" , pcu_rtc_day , "  " , pcu_rtc_hour, ":" , pcu_rtc_minute, ":" , pcu_rtc_secound) FROM site_values where site_id = " , i);
```

Also the since you are using 2 CONCAT statements the quotes may be a problem.  You could try this:

```
concat("INSERT ignore INTO `site_values_" , i , "` (report_time) SELECT  CONCAT(pcu_rtc_year , '-' , pcu_rtc_month , '-' , pcu_rtc_day , '  ' , pcu_rtc_hour, ':' , pcu_rtc_minute, ':' , pcu_rtc_secound) FROM site_values where site_id = " , i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your SQL not construct a syntax error:

```
"...SELECT  CONCAT(", "pcu_rtc_year" , "-" , "pcu_rtc_month" , "-" , "pcu_rtc_day" , "  " , "pcu_rtc_hour" , ":" , " pcu_
```

will result in

```
SELECT CONCAT(pcu_rtc_year-pcu_rtc_month-pcu_rtc_day pcu_rtc_hour:pcu...)
```

It seems you are missing commas there.

```
"...SELECT  CONCAT(", "pcu_rtc_year," , "'-'," , "pcu_rtc_month," , "'-'," , "pcu_rtc_day," , "'  '," , "pcu_rtc_hour," , "':'," , " pcu_...)
```

Resulting:

```
SELECT CONCAT(pcu_rtc_year,'-',pcu_rtc_month,'-',pcu_rtc_day,' ',pcu_rtc_hour,':',pcu...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes in there, and getting mixed up in the two concats:

```
set @t =  concat("INSERT ignore INTO `site_values_" , i , "` (report_time)",
     "SELECT CONCAT(pcu_rtc_year, '-', pcu_rtc_month, '-', pcu_rtc_day, '  ',
                    pcu_rtc_hour, ':', pcu_rtc_minute, ':', pcu_rtc_secound)",
     "FROM site_values where site_id =" , i);
```